# SQL: Prevent a combination of items from being inserted twice

Tags: mysql, sql

When you make a field unique, it can only be inserted once. Is there a way to make two fields unique when they are used together or is there an SQL syntax that would allow me to do that?

I have a userID and an itemNr. Users can have as many item numbers as they want and currently they simply get inserted. This means I cannot set them UNIQUE.

However, I want to prevent that the same combination is in the DB twice.

I know how to do it programmatically (first select an item, then check if it matches the one you want to insert, if so, update it).

Is there a more elegant way using direct SQL syntax? I use MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a compound unique constraint:

```
alter table your_table
    add constraint your_unique_key unique (col1, col2)
/
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I knew there was a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simply defining each column as unique (which sets each one up as independently unique), declare a "compound unique key", where the combination of two or more column values must be unique across all rows of the table. The basic syntax is:

```
ALTER myTable ADD CONSTRAINT myTable_Unique_ColumnA_ColumnB UNIQUE (ColumnA, ColumnB)
```

Comment: I believe there is no `NONCLUSTERED` modifier for ALTER TABLE in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This is done with unique constraints. For example, if your table is called table1, you can do something like that:

alter table table1
add constraint c1 unique(userID, itemNr);